# azure functions -running npm install on azure portal

Tags: node.js, azure, function, npm, console

This is a how to question, not a problem

I would like use an npm package in my javascript Azure function.  How do I get a console in the azure functions portal to run npm install?  If there is a better way to reference the npm package, this will answer my question too. A documentation reference with an example of installing the npm package in an
Azure function would also be appreciated.

I apologize for this basic question.  I am new to both node and azure functions and have enjoyed learning what I have so far, but this simple procedure is eluding me.

Thank you for any help you can give me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the KUDU console at https://yourfunctionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net and navigate to the wwwroot folder and install the package that you need!

Here is an [`article`](https://sajeetharan.com/2020/01/10/want-to-alert-your-employees-to-have-a-break-at-work-azure-function-can-help-you/) that i wrote to showcase how you can install python packages!

However when you deploy the azure function [`package.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node) will have all the dependencies and you dont need to install them separately.

Comment: This was what I needed.  Thank you.  The article you wrote had the right amount of detail so that Kudu was easy to implement and not intimidating

Comment: These features probably are not available in consumption plan, at least I don't see them even I login to Kudu.

Comment: I recently created an azure function app(nodejs-v18.2) & created a Eventhub JavaScript trigger inside it via "azure portal". I learned it d hard way(Im from Java world) that the portal doesn't create a package.json for you initially via portal but rather provides few files(index.js, host.json, function.json) by default. When I tried executing my index.js from portal directly without knowing the requirement of libs(I assumed azure will getem for me) I ended up getting an error: "Unable to find jsforce/nodejs" Later via Kudu CMD I manually created package.json & ran install commands

Comment: As I've managed to create a function & eventhub JS trigger via azure portal - now I want to modify the content & open this project in my VScode app for further upgrades but I don't see options in VScode. All files are "read-only" mode & there is only "create" option in the azure extension of vscode/intelliJ but no option for "open/update" an existing azure app that was created via azure portal - how do I do this? Further I also wud like to deploy my JSON/JS code changes to azure trigger & I dont intend to use a git repo for a serverless function as it has less files. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Assume the function name is function677761

---

Step1. Open the browser and visit the Kudo console.
https://function677761.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

---

Step2. In the toolbar menu select  DebugConsole/CMD

---

Step3. Run the commands:

C:\home>ls

C:\home>cd .\site\wwwroot

C:\home\site\wwwroot>npm i date-and-time

C:\home> ls

---

Step4. My output is

HttpTrigger1

host.json

node_modules

package-lock.json

package.json

---

Step5. Now inside the file package.json there is the node.js library date-and-time just installed.

"dependencies": {
"date-and-time": "^2.4.2"
}

---

Step6. I can read the file package.json from here.

https://portal.azure.com/#@myemail345.onmicrosoft.com/resource/subscriptions/3877920b-027777-4513-8777a-ca378888917/resourcegroups/group001/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/function677761/functionsAppFiles

These values are custom.
Depend by my account.

myemail345

group001

function677761

3877920b-027777-4513-8777a-ca378888917

---

Source1.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings

Section.
Manually install extensions .

Source2.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2-v3-v4-export%2Cv2-v3-v4-done%2Cv2%2Cv2-log-custom-telemetry%2Cv2-accessing-request-and-response%2Cwindows-setting-the-node-version

Section.
Folder structure